# What is prelinking in the context of ld.so mean and how does LD_TRACE_PRELINKING affect it

Tags: linker, ld

I'm trying to understand all the ways can I manipulate `ld.so`, and I can't understand the documentation for the `LD_TRACE_PRELINKING` environment variable.

The manpage says:

```
       LD_TRACE_PRELINKING (since glibc 2.4)
              If this environment variable is defined, trace prelinking of the object whose name is assigned to this environment variable.  (Use ldd(1) to get a list of the objects that might be traced.)  If the object name is not recognized, then
              all prelinking activity is traced.
```

Which is not terribly useful since I can't find any information about what is **prelinking** of an object in the context `ld.so`, and whether or not it's also traced when activating `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS`.

So, what is **prelinking** in `ld.so` and how does `LD_TRACE_PRELINKING` affects `ld.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic loader/linker (like `ld.so`) has to perform symbol resolution and binding operations at the start of program execution and when shared libraries are dynamically loaded. Some of these activities can be performed in advance without actually executing program code and the results can be cached for use during actual execution. This improves startup time and overall program execution time. On linux, `prelink` is the tool that drives this optimization, with the core functionality implemented in `ld.so`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Any links I can follow for more details?

Comment: I found some good ones in the first few web search results. Once you have read them, you could post more specific questions. In general LD_TRACE_* should enable tracing messages from the dynamic linker/loader about the specific functionalities.